# Selenium tests independent of OS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to do my tests independent of OS. It have to run them both on Windows and Linux. I have a problem with `path` to `WebDrivers`. Pathes to `WebDrivers` are saved in `config.properties` file like this:

```
chrome=C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Documents\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe
firefox=C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Documents\\selenium\\Firefox_GeckoDriver\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe
```

How can I do to make it universal? I was thinking about sth with `relative path` and `File.separator` but I don't know how to start with it.

Comment: Do you have to specify the paths in code? You could just set a system environment variable so you don't have to worry about it at all.

Comment: @RemcoW but how can linux know about the WebDrivers without paths?

Comment: maintain the folder structure of the project and keep driver executables in one of the project folders, lets say `/lib`. then, you can use the relative paths w.r.t. project root folder and + "/lib" would give the location. Use forward slash, which is supported in all OSes.

Comment: @Naveen thank you very much!